# Sending and receiving custom signals in Django and ensuring it is atomic

Tags: python, django, database, backend, atomic

I want to create a custom signal and send the signal after some database operations. The receiver also performs database operations. I want to make sure all the database operations before sending the signal and in the signal, receiver is atomic meaning either all fail, or all succeed.

Consider the following code:

```py
def send_my_signal():
    # Database operation 1
    # Database Operation 2
    my_signal.send(sender=MyModel)
```

The receiver:

```py
@receiver(my_signal)
def my_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
    # Database operation 3
    # Database operation 4
```

I want either all database operations 1 to 4 succeed or fail together.
By asking from generative AI models, one proposed solution is to wrap the body of the function that performs database operations and sends the signal inside the `transaction.atomic()` context manager. So, the code would look like this:

```py
def send_my_signal():
    with transaction.atomic():
        # Database operation 1
        # Database Operation 2
        my_signal.send(sender=MyModel)
```

But I could not find any resource or anything in Django documentation confirming this. It's not like I am calling the receiver of the signal inside the `transaction.atomic()` context manager, I am just sending the signal there.